# echoing the error null when there is no matched data in database

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I created a simple form that searches the match of the entered username to one in database and displays its first name and last name. I'm having a problem in displaying error. It is supposed to be displaying null or nothing when the username entered doesn't match with the username in the database. I tried echoing null in the else statement, but it still displays the error message.

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=sample;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM search WHERE username=:username");
    $query->execute(['username' => $search]);

    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if(count($row)) {
        echo $row->firstname . ' ' . $row->lastname;
    } else {
        echo null;
    }
}
```

This is not supposed to be showing:
[image]

Comment: `echo $row->firstname . ' ' . $row->lastname;` is line 14? Have you tried condtionalling the `fetch`?

Comment: already fixed the issue...

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question if you think this could be useful for other people. At the same time, I would try to add reproducible details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
 if(count($row) > 0) {
    echo $row->firstname . ' ' . $row->lastname;
} else {
    echo null;
}
```

Comment: first of all check that Object $row in empty or NOT . Do print_r($row);